# How to show that $\sinh^2(x) \ge x^2$

Tags: inequality

How to show that $\sinh^2(x) \ge x^2$? I need it to proof something else and i can clearly see that it's true by graphing it. I just can't come up with an easy solution to show it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using the infinite series expansion of $\sinh(x)=x + \frac{x^3}{3!} + \frac{x^5}{5!}+\frac{x^7}{7!}+\cdots$.
\begin{align} \sinh^2(x) &= \left(x + \frac{x^3}{3!} + \frac{x^5}{5!}+\frac{x^7}{7!}+\cdots \right)^2 \\ &=\left[x \left(1+\frac{x^2}{3!}+\frac{x^4}{5!}+\frac{x^6}{7!}+\cdots \right)\right]^2 \\ &= x^2  \left(1+\frac{x^2}{3!}+\frac{x^4}{5!}+\frac{x^6}{7!}+\cdots   \right)^2 \\ &\ge x^2(1)^2 & \text{for all real numbers $x$}\\ &= x^2  \end{align}

Answer (score 6):

$$
\begin{align}
\sinh(x)^2
&=\left(\frac{e^x-e^{-x}}{2}\right)^2\\
&=\frac{1}{4}(e^{2x}+e^{-2x}-2)\\
&=\frac{1}{4}\left(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(2x)^n}{n!}+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-2x)^n}{n!}-2\right)\\
&=\frac{1}{4}\left(2\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(2x)^{2n}}{(2n)!}-2\right)\\
&\geq\frac{1}{4}(2(1+2x^2)-2)\\
&=x^2
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 4):

Both functions are even, hence it suffices to show that $\sinh x > x$ for any $x\in\mathbb{R}^+$. This is trivial since $\sinh x$ is a convex function over $\mathbb{R}^+\cup\{0\}$, due to $\sinh'' x=\sinh x$ and $\sinh 0 = 0$, $\sinh' 0 = 1$.

Answer (score 4):

Let $f(x) = \sinh x - x$.

Then $f'(x) = \cosh x - 1$. $f'(x)$ is positive everywhere except when $x = 0$, in which case $f'(0) = 0$.

Therefore, $f(0)$ is the minimum value of $f$, and so

$$ f(x) \geq f(0) = 0 $$

i.e.

$$\sinh x - x \geq 0 $$

Answer (score 3):

Notice that  $\sinh$ is a  convex function on $[0,\infty)$ so it's curve is above the tangent line at the point $(0,0)$ with equation $y=x$. We deduce the desired inequality on $\Bbb R$ using the fact that it's an odd function.

Answer (score 2):

For $x \geq 0$, integrate the inequality $\cosh(t)=\sqrt{\sinh^2(t)+1} \geq 1$ from $0$ to $x$. For $x<0$, use $\sinh(-x)=-\sinh(x)$.

Answer (score 1):

Use the Pythagorean identity with $\cosh x$, then use the series for the function

Comment: Does anybody really call $\cosh^2 x - \sinh^2 x = 1$ the "Pythagorean identity with $\cosh x$?"

Comment: @ThomasAndrews, it got called that (by analogy, I think) in my calculus class way back when...

Comment: Yeah, I just don't think that it is a usual name, and was suggesting you clarify....

Answer (score 1):

$\sinh x = \frac{1}2(e^x-e^{-x})$ so $$\sinh^2 x = \frac{1}{4}\left(e^{2x} - 2 +e^{-2x}\right) = -1/2 + \frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(2x)^{2n}}{(2n)!}\geq -\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}+ \frac{1}{2}\frac{(2x)^2}{2!}= x^2$$

Basically, $\cosh x \geq 1 + \frac{1}{2}x^2$, and $\sinh^2 x = \frac12\left(-1 + \cosh 2x\right)$.

Answer (score 0):

Since $t\mapsto e^t$ is convex, by Jensen's inequality we have
$$ \frac{\sinh x}{x} = \frac{e^x-e^{-x}}{2x} = \frac1{2x}\int_{-x}^x e^t \,dt \ge e^{\frac1{2x}\int_{-x}^x t\,dt} = e^0 = 1 $$
Squaring and multiplying by $x^2$ yields the desired result.